# Save captured image into mlmodel and compare it for face classification when face classification view

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, coreml

i want to build an app that keeps detecting face and the person itself from front camera.
i watch this tutorial

```
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/face-recognition-and-detection-on-ios-using-native-swift-code-core-ml-and-arkit-feed10c468da
```

but i'm confused because i don't know how to save the captured image from front camera and add into the model.

How can i save captured image into mlmodel and compare it for face classification when i'm segue into next page?
thank you.

Comment: you can capture the face detection photo but you can not save your captured photo in mlmodel because it is pre-trained data/image model.

Comment: Is there any way to save the captured photo and compare it for face classification when i'm segue into next page sir?

Comment: You can get comparable photo already in observation so you dont need to compare in any separate way....you can pass your observation directly to the next page.